# Custom Object Export Array and Add to the array

Tags: arrays, powershell, object

I am having difficulty understanding what I am missing.
I am trying to do 2 things, I am trying to build a custom object array, then later add to the custom object array with more data.  Then Finally Export the full custom object array to a csv.  I know I am close but all I am getting is "Object" for the custom object array.

The object appears intact in Add-ArraySiteDefaultvsUserSettings and when it leave that function but then I can not build on the object and it be usefull.

```
    Function Add-DefaultsValidation 
{
    #New-Object psobject -Property @{IdenTity = '';SiteDefault = '';UserSetting = '';IssueAlert =''}
    $DefaultsObject = New-Object Object -TypeName PSObject
    Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name SiteCode -Value "" -InputObject $DefaultsObject  
    Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Identity -Value "" -InputObject $DefaultsObject
    Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name OU -Value "" -InputObject $DefaultsObject    
    Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name SiteDefault -Value "" -InputObject $DefaultsObject  
    Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name UserSetting -Value "" -InputObject $DefaultsObject  
    Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name IssueAlert -Value "" -InputObject $DefaultsObject  
    $DefaultsObject
}

Function Add-ArraySiteDefaultvsUserSettings
{
    Param ( $OU, $Identity, $SiteCode, $SiteDefaultValue, $UserCurrentSettings, $AlertType )

    #SiteDefaultvsUserSettings
    [array]$DefaultvsUserSettings = @()
    $addObject = Add-DefaultsValidation
    $addObject.SiteCode = $SiteCode
    $addObject.Identity = $Identity
    $addObject.OU = $OU
    $addObject.SiteDefault = $SiteDefaultValue
    $addObject.UserSetting = $UserCurrentSettings
    $addObject.IssueAlert = $AlertType
    $DefaultvsUserSettings += $addObject
    #Write-Output $SiteDefaultvsUserSettings

    Return $DefaultvsUserSettings
}

foreach ($SkypeSiteDefault in $SkypeSiteDefaults)
{

    if ($SkypeSiteDefault.OU -ne $null)
    {
        $SkypeSiteDefault.'Site Code'
        $SkypeSiteDefault.RegistrarPool
            $SkypeUsersRegistrarInvalid = Get-CsUser -ResultSize unlimited -ou $SkypeSiteDefault.OU | Where-Object {$_.RegistrarPool.FriendlyName -notlike "*$($SkypeSiteDefault.RegistrarPool)*"} | Select SamAccountName, Registrarpool 
            if ($SkypeUsersRegistrarInvalid.count -ne 0)
            {
                foreach ($SkypeUserRegistrarInvalid in $SkypeUsersRegistrarInvalid)
                {
                    $myOU = $SkypeUserRegistrarInvalid.Identity | ForEach-Object{($_ -split "," | Select-Object -Skip 2)} 
                    $UserOU = $myOU -join ','

                    [array]$SkypeUserInvalidObjectAttribute = @()
                    $SkypeUserInvalidObjectAttribute = 
                        Add-ArraySiteDefaultvsUserSettings `
                            -SiteCode $SkypeSiteDefault.'Site Code' `
                            -Identity $SkypeUserRegistrarInvalid.SamAccountName `
                            -OU $UserOU `
                            -SiteDefaultValue $SkypeSiteDefault.RegistrarPool `
                            -UserCurrentSettings $SkypeUserRegistrarInvalid.Registrarpool.FriendlyName `
                            -AlertType 'INVALID - REGISTRAR POOL' 


                    If ($SkypeUsersInvalidObjectAttribute.count -eq 0)
                    {
                        $SkypeUsersInvalidObjectAttribute = $SkypeUserInvalidObjectAttribute
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $SkypeUsersInvalidObjectAttribute += $SkypeUserInvalidObjectAttribute
                    }

                }
            }


            #Get-CsUser -ResultSize unlimited -ou $SkypeSiteDefault.OU | Where-Object {$_.Registrarpool -ne $SkypeSiteDefault.RegistrarPool} | Select SamAccountName, Registrarpool


        $SkypeSiteDefault.'Site Code'
        $SkypeSiteDefault.'Dial Plan'

        $SkypeSiteDefault.'Site Code'
        $SkypeSiteDefault.'Voice Policy'

        Write-Host ''
        Write-Host ''

    }
}

$SkypeUsersInvalidObjectAttribute | Export-CSV "C:\Scriptout\Test.csv"
```

Comment: What version of Powershell are you running this in?  I am only asking because if you are running on PS Version 5, I would just create classes as the custom objects.  Be a lot easier to manage.  Looks like you are using a function as a class creator in this.

Comment: Version 5 do you have a sample

Comment: I can not tell you how helpfull this modification helped.

Comment: https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2015/09/01/powershell-5-create-simple-class/

Comment: Class ObjectCompare
{
    [String] $SiteCode
    [String] $Identity
    [String] $OU
    [String] $SiteDefault
    [String] $UserSetting
    [String] $IssueAlert
}

Comment: Function Add-ArraySiteDefaultvsUserSettings
{
    Param ( $OU, $Identity, $SiteCode, $SiteDefaultValue, $UserCurrentSettings, $AlertType )
    
    #SiteDefaultvsUserSettings
    $addObject = New-Object ObjectCompare 
    $addObject.SiteCode = $SiteCode
    $addObject.Identity = $Identity
    $addObject.OU = $OU
    $addObject.SiteDefault = $SiteDefaultValue
    $addObject.UserSetting = $UserCurrentSettings
    $addObject.IssueAlert = $AlertType
    $DefaultvsUserSettings += $addObject
    #Write-Output $SiteDefaultvsUserSettings

    Return $DefaultvsUserSettings
}

Comment: Worked Beautifully Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Parrish - Thank you a lot for your answer:  A Class is exactly the solution I needed.

```
    Class ObjectCompare
{
    [String] $SiteCode
    [String] $Identity
    [String] $OU
    [String] $SiteDefault
    [String] $UserSetting
    [String] $IssueAlert
}


Function Add-ArraySiteDefaultvsUserSettings
{
    Param ( $OU, $Identity, $SiteCode, $SiteDefaultValue, $UserCurrentSettings, $AlertType )

    #SiteDefaultvsUserSettings
    [array]$DefaultvsUserSettings = @()
    $addObject = New-Object ObjectCompare # Add-DefaultsValidation
    $addObject.SiteCode = $SiteCode
    $addObject.Identity = $Identity
    $addObject.OU = $OU
    $addObject.SiteDefault = $SiteDefaultValue
    $addObject.UserSetting = $UserCurrentSettings
    $addObject.IssueAlert = $AlertType
    $DefaultvsUserSettings += $addObject
    #Write-Output $SiteDefaultvsUserSettings

    Return $DefaultvsUserSettings
}
```

Comment: NP.  If I remember, you cannot add empty properties to an object with add-member.  I maybe wrong but I had an issue doing that.  To use add-member, you have to have the value ready to be inserted.